# Failed to render in blender on Mac OSX

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, osx

When i tried rendering in blender a message says :"could not initialise streams probably unsupported codec combination"

I tried rendering with different files. 
I'm using a macbook, what can I do?

Comment: Is it possible to attach a simple .blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ link , so we could probably spot the problem? Do you have a camera in your scene? Also include the blender version you are using and also the engine you are trying to render from ... eg. Blender render or Cycles?

Answer (score 1):

Not all video output options work on OSX. I'm assuming you're using a video format? You'll have to experiment to see which ones work on your machine.